# How to troubleshoot ACCESS DENIED in code deploy for DownloadBundle stage

Tags: aws-code-deploy

The attached screenshot is the error. There are no stderr messages for me to troubleshoot. I have already set the necessary EC2 IAM access to S3. So what could be the problem?

[[image: 1]]
[[image: 2]]

I have also add in the user requirements for IAM, so I am not sure what is wrong

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-ap-southeast-1-617020163322/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-us-east-2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-us-west-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-us-west-2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ca-central-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-eu-west-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-eu-west-2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-eu-west-3/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-eu-central-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-ap-south-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-codedeploy-sa-east-1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Had the same issue, and resolved by looking up destination instances IAM role (under instance description tab) and attached S3 access policy.

Comment: If you are deploying to an EC2 instance, and the CodeDeploy agent on that machine is pulling an artifact from S3, you need to make sure that the EC2 IAM instance role has permissions to access S3.

Comment: Do you have a link to instructions on attaching this s3 Policy?  What is the policy name? etc...?

Comment: Also note that if you're using a KMS key to encrypt the build artifacts in the S3 bucket, the instance profile will also need a policy that allows access to the KMS key.

Answer (score 7):

The errors associated to the DownloadBundle lifecycle event are:

1. The bucket is in a different region than the pipeline (which I can
   see from your screenshot is not).
2. Because the [IAM instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-ec2-configure.html#instances-ec2-configure-2-verify-instance-profile-permissions) attached to your EC2 instance does not have permissions to access the application
   revision in Amazon S3.

Is the bucket "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-ap-southeast-1-617020163322" where the bundle is store? Was this folder created by CodePipeline?

If yes, my recommendation is to use a different bucket than the bucket used by CodePipeline to store the artifacts. Especially because you will need to have a [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-create-prerequisites.html#deployment-prerequisites-server) to grant your instances the permissions required to download the application revision.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue and was able to resolve it.  I forgot to add permission to KMS in my EC2 Assume Role. My S3 artifact bucket uses KMS Encryption hence since CodePipeline uses KMS, it throws ACCESS DENIED to the S3 bucket.  The error though is not friendly enough to tell the user what is the actual problem.

Comment: That worked for me! It's annoying to be sent delving into S3 permissions & IAM policies by the "Access Denied" statement :-(

Comment: I could not agree more. I just spent DAYS chasing this down, assuming it had something to do with cross-account issues, etc. It was not until I broke it down to the simplest steps that I realised the error was with the KMS key not granting permissions to the instance profile role. Ugh. Your comment helped put me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: What policy permission did you choose?

Comment: It's been a while, but to make it more simple, use kms:* . If you want lease privilege please look at the decrypt portion of the actions table -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awskeymanagementservice.html

Answer (score 2):

Just to add more possible solutions to this issue as I just ran into it today.

My issue was using a custom artifacts bucket (aka, not one created by CodePipeline) which was supposed to have versioning off (suspended) and my EC2 Profile had the following permissions:

```
          "Effect": 
           "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
```

Adding `s3:GetObjectVersion` to the EC2 Policy on my CodeDeploy boxes fixed the problem.

This was quite confusing has versioning was turned off.

tldr; When in doubt, give versioning permissions.